# zend send email to refer a friend

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, parameters, param

I have a page to send invite email to friend.

When you enter your friend email and it's send.

Your friend receive the email and in that email he has a link that goes to a page to refer the user.

Here's my question: when the friend click on that link, is it possible to get this friend email as a parameter on put it into the url of that link???

So, when that friend click the link it will save this friend email into Database.

if I have a URL like this: www.mywebsite.com/dasdasd324gb2h423g?email=myemail@gmail.com

how can I get the myemail@gmail.com????

Comment: Yesm you just have to change the link action to do what you want.

Comment: And oh yea, the refer app I did, is pretty similar to dropbox referral. just don't know how to grab the information of the email send when he click on the link to refer me.

Answer (score 0):

You must put e-mail as URI parameter to href attribute in message sending time. There is no any possibility to get receiver's email at view-time. And there is no real need to do that way.

As better solution you can save every sent message as unique invite (with corresponding email address) in your database and put some unique invite code to the link (like example.com/inv?eii54u3ksm5553)

Comment: yea it's true what you say, I have a send email DB with a foreign key link to the user who send that email. But, I am so confuse, the user can send multiple email to refer friends. So, how can the friend who want to refer the user knows is that friend who refer him. Sorry, I am still news in programming, maybe my logic doesn't make sense.